# Responsive Input fields with Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap, angular

I know we have multiple bootstrap and VF page libraries available.But i have a very specific requirement where I want to display all possible input fields of Salesforce on a responsive framework including look up fields and rich text fields etc.

Any inputs on same. Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use apex:inputfield for lookups and Rich text.Also for date time and date fields you will see huge difference.

For these specific that don't work well ,you can build angular directives so that you can reuse everywhere.

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks for the details. Will directives help in case of look up fields in a generic way?

Comment: If you create a simple directive in angular to handle lookup you can reuse .It depends on how proficient you feel with angular .

Comment: lol..then there is still some time.. Anyways thanks for same. If there is any blog / resource on same do let me know.

Comment: Check this http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/24/typeahead-with-angular/    .You may have to just wire that to a Remoting function